# How to get caret position in Google Chrome by C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

I am trying to implement window app to get text cursor position as user typing , it works well in other applications but not for Google Chrome. Is there any way to get caret position in window application implementation, I am using C#.

I appreciate any advance or suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you using C# inside Chrome?

Comment: have you looked at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application